# Can NSManagedObject class objects be used as models?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a bit confusion in choosing whether to use NSManagedObjet class objects directly as models or whether to create separate classess for models and create data mappers to map data from these model class to NSManagedObject class objects. 
Is there any harm in using Core Data objects as models ? What are the pros and cons of both approches?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

tek3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your question and I take it you are not asking whether to use NSManagedObject directly or whether to subclass NSManagedObject, but if you should have your model as separate classes which use Core Data by explicit methods written by yourself.

Core Data is designed to act as the model layer for your application. I do not see any real benefits in having your own model classes, writing an interface for them and implementing it in core data behind the scenes, unless you really need the freedom to give up core data entirely at some point.

I recommend you create your model classes as subclasses of NSManagedObject. You are free to extend those in any way you deem necessary beyond what core data provides you, but at the same time your model classes will have full benefits from the core data framework: faulting, caching, data integrity assurances, cascade deletes, etc...

Comment: Hi Svena, thanks for the reply. But what should be done in case I want my model object to be shared across different classess. In that case model classes of type  NSManagedObject will not work.

Comment: Can you bring an example of such case?

Comment: I have a class Meetings.
Meetings class has following attributes : Organizer, list of Attendees, location  and start time.
For entering each of these information I have different view controllers which are pushed one after another. So what I wanted is to create an object of type Meetings and pass it to next view controller (as property). So that in the end I have an meetings object with complete information.
Is this possible with objects of type NSManagedObject.

Comment: Absolutely. You will create a property "meeting" for each view controller working with meeting object and pass it on through the view hierarchy either through -prepareForSegue:sender (if you use storyboards) or in whatever method prior to -pushViewController:animated.

Comment: So so we declare it as @property(nonatomic, retain) DTMeeting* meeting and in .m file synthesize the meeting property. So do we have to release the meeting property explicitly in dealloc method ? I have read that NSManagedObject handles its life cycle on its own.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the way to do it. And yes, it does handle the lifecycle on its own, but that does not mean that you should not retain it for your own use and release it when you're done with it. Whether the object itself lives until its usefulness wears out for Core Data Framework is not your worry anymore.

Comment: Well, almost all my queries are cleared now. Thank yo very much I just have one more question. Can NSManagedObject class objects be also added as IBOutlets in xib ? I guess that they cant be added as IBOutlets because in this case their designated initialiser will not be called.

Comment: Outlets are used to setup references to objects that are serialized into xib and instantiated from there. No you cannot do that with a managed object. Perhaps if you could bring an example why you would want to do that, I could offer some suggestions.

Comment: Sorry SO is not allowing me to explain my context to you. So I have explained my scenario in chat.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use `NSManagedObject`, you will not have the benefit of the convenient "dot.notation" when referring to attributes and relationships.

Also, you will have to retrieve all values with `valueForKey` and set them with `setValueForKey` followed by strings. This can be extremely error prone and cumbersome and the resulting code is not nearly as readably as with the dot notation.

Finally, in your object classes you can implement all kinds of additional functionality. Where would you put this code otherwise? Remember the principle of *encapsulation* that helps produce independent and reusable code.